# How to convert exist Block Blob to PageBlob

Tags: azure

I used the CloudBerry explorer to copy the VM(Iaas) disk file to a another Storage.
But when I finished duplication, I found the new create Blob is a Block Blob, not a Page Blob.
The tool didn't duplicate the source blob type which is Page Blob.
Is there anyway to Convert to Page Blob from Block Blob? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Once a blob is created/uploaded you can't change the blob type. Unfortunately you would need to recreate/re-upload the blob. However I'm somewhat surprised. You mentioned that you copied the blob from one storage account to another. Copy Blob operation within Windows Azure (i.e. from one storage account to another) preserves the source blob type. It may seem a bug in CloudBerry explorer. I wrote a blog post some days ago about moving virtual machines from one subscription to another (http://gauravmantri.com/2012/07/04/how-to-move-windows-azure-virtual-machines-from-one-subscription-to-another/) and it has some sample code and other useful information for copying blobs across storage account. You may want to take a look at that. HTH.

Comment: Yes , It is a bug , Maybe there are more features in the Prod Version of it . I am not sure that , I am using the free trial of the Cloud Storage Studio. It is good enough for me. Thanks, you do a great job.

Comment: Anyway, Can you recommend any free good windows azure tool to me? ;)

Comment: Tough question, considering all the things! :) Try CloudXplorer from ClumsyLeaf though I'm not sure if it supports asynchronous copy blob yet. Also a big thing with VHDs is that the tool should support sparse uploads which Cloud Storage Studio does so that you don't end up uploading empty pages. The blog post in my answer above has a working console application that you can use for copying blobs across storage accounts. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Has been a while since the original question, but it seems that the solution I used is not known or at least is not being used.

In Azure Storage you can not change the blob type for an existing file. Some people recommends download the files and upload again. But you can also use azcopy from the Cloud Shell in the Azure portal. At least in PowerShell the azcopy utility is available. I haven't  tried in bash.

You need 2 SAS URLs with addecuate permission to read from the original container and to write to the destination. You also need the LIST permission. Having that, open the Cloud Shell and write the command.

```
azcopy copy 'https://<source-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<source-container-name>?<SAS-token>' 'https://<dest-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<dest-container-name>?<SAS-token>' --recursive --blob-type=BlockBlob
```

After coping, just delete the old page blobs.

More options for azcopy copy command can be found [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-copy).

This is the sample output:

[image: sample output of the azcopy copy command in Cloud Shell]