# Good tool for windows azure storage

Tags: azure

I have used the #1[Azure Storage Explorer](http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/) from coldplex and #2[Cloud Berry explorer](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-amazon-s3-explorer-cloudfront-IAM.aspx). but I am not satisfied with the poor functions of the #1.
and #2 has a little bug with the duplication of blob which I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851764/how-to-convert-exist-block-blob-to-pageblob). So somebody can recommend some good tools for me ? First choice it is better for free.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post may help you too: http://wely-lau.net/2012/09/25/an-independent-review-of-explorer-tools-for-windows-azure-blob-storage/

Comment: unfortunatelly, post no longer available

Answer (score 6):

Cerebrata now offer a free Windows Azure storage tool called Azure Explorer.

http://www.cerebrata.com/labs/azure-explorer

[image: Screenshot of Azure Explorer]

Answer (score 3):

[Cloud Combine](http://www.gapotchenko.com/cloudcombine) makes managing azure blob storage easy.

Answer (score 2):

The free version of CloudXplorer works great: http://clumsyleaf.com/products/cloudxplorer

Comment: I like Stackoverflow! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of the tools from Cerebrta - www.cerebrata.com.  Try the trial for free to see if you like it.  If so, the price is WELL worth the time savings.